# Reverse an ongoing CSS transition using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I'm building a menu that slides in and out when a trigger is activated. It works as expected, except when clicking the trigger *before* the transition has had time to finish. What I would like  to happen is for the menu to smoothly transition back to the previous state. Here is a codepen with the current menu: https://codepen.io/luchian/pen/RwQexyQ. An example of the desired behavior can be found here: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/overlay/menu#usage. Notice how, no matter how quickly the trigger button is clicked, menu transitions are smooth.

Am I supposed to listen for a particular event, or use getComputedStyle() to dynamically add property values during transitions? Are there any other solutions?

HTML

```html
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <button class="button button-neutral" data-toggle="menu-1" aria-expanded="false">Best</button>
  <ul id="menu-1" class="menu">
    <li>
      <a class="menu-action" href="">Books</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="menu-action" href="">Authors</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-separator">
      <a class="menu-action" href="">Genres</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="menu-action" href="">Themes</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS Transitions

```css
.slide-regular-enter,
.slide-regular-leave {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
}

.slide-regular-enter-from,
.slide-regular-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(1rem);
}

.slide-regular-enter-to,
.slide-regular-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

JavaScript Display Transition Helper

```js
const CLASS_SHOWN = "shown";

function transitionDisplay(element, effect, timing = "regular") {
  const phase = element.classList.contains(CLASS_SHOWN) ? "leave" : "enter";
  const transition = `${effect}-${timing}-${phase}`;
  const transitionFrom = `${transition}-from`;
  const transitionTo = `${transition}-to`;
  const isEntering = phase === "enter" ? true : false;

  if (isEntering) element.classList.add(CLASS_SHOWN);

  element.classList.add(transition);
  element.classList.add(transitionFrom);

  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      element.classList.remove(transitionFrom);
      element.classList.add(transitionTo);

      element.addEventListener(
        "transitionend",
        () => {
          if (!isEntering) {
            element.classList.remove(CLASS_SHOWN);
          }
          element.classList.remove(transition);
          element.classList.remove(transitionTo);
        },
        { once: true }
      );
    });
  });
}

export default transitionDisplay;
```

Menu Component

```js
import transitionDisplay from "../../helpers/transition-display";

const SELECTOR_MENU = ".menu";
const CLASS_ACTIVATED = "activated";
const CLASS_SHOWN = "shown";
const DATA_TOGGLE = "data-toggle";

function Menu(menu) {
  const menuId = menu.id;
  const trigger = document.querySelector(`[${DATA_TOGGLE}="${menuId}"]`);
  const focusableElements = Array.from(menu.querySelectorAll(":where(a[href], button, input):not([tabindex^='-'], [disabled])"));
  const lastFocusableElement = focusableElements[focusableElements.length - 1];

  function toggle() {
    const isShown = menu.classList.contains(CLASS_SHOWN);

    isShown ? hide() : show();
  }

  function show() {
    trigger.classList.add(CLASS_ACTIVATED);
    trigger.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
    transitionDisplay(menu, "slide");

    trigger.addEventListener("keydown", handleTabKeydown);
    menu.addEventListener("keydown", handleTabKeydown);
    document.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleEscapeKeydown);
  }

  function hide() {
    trigger.classList.remove(CLASS_ACTIVATED);
    trigger.setAttribute("aria-expanded", false);
    transitionDisplay(menu, "slide");

    trigger.removeEventListener("keydown", handleTabKeydown);
    menu.removeEventListener("keydown", handleTabKeydown);
    document.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleEscapeKeydown);
  }

  function handleOutsideClick(event) {
    if (!trigger.contains(event.target) && !menu.contains(event.target)) {
      hide();
    }
  }

  function handleEscapeKeydown(event) {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
      hide();
    }
  }

  function handleTabKeydown(event) {
    if (event.key === "Tab" && ((event.shiftKey && document.activeElement === trigger) || (!event.shiftKey && document.activeElement === lastFocusableElement))) {
      hide();
    }
  }

  trigger.addEventListener("click", toggle);
}

export { Menu, SELECTOR_MENU };
```